# Sorting a String by its 6 first characters

Tags: java, string, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I have IDs with the following format : XXXXXXYYY00000

What I am trying to do is to get a single string organised alphabetically by the 6 first characters (the 6 x's (they can be any character)) with each new ID separated by a new line character

For example :

AOPSIKPMI23495 would go before BWLMBEPMI00001

What I have so far is :

```
String = String + this.ID + "\n";
```

And I have no idea how to approach my problem in order to solve it.

My question is the following : How do I organise my IDs alphabetically, only by its first 6 characters (meaning if there's a tie with the 6 first characters, it still shouldn't resolve it with the next 3 characters) and still keeping my String ?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it is a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: What does sorting by the six first characters even mean? Just sort the strings, and by definition they would also be sorted by the first six characters

Comment: Most likely answer will be to use a stream and group by the prefix.

Comment: I'm not having a compiler effort. I'm not compiling at all, I'm trying to ask a question in order to learn something I don't know about. It's not verifiable and I'd rather not show the rest of the code I'm working on because it is absolutely useless and does not bring anything to my question.

Comment: Sorting by the first six characters means that if I "just sort", it will also consider the next 3 characters. That is not what I want and that I why I want it to be sorted alphabetically by the first six characters. It's also why I didn't only ask for it to be sorted and why I added a precision to it.

Comment: It will only consider the next 3 characters in the case of ties. If that’s not what you want you need to specify in the question what you do want to happen if there are ties.

Comment: To clarify why sorting on the whole string won't work, I suspect the term you're looking for is "stable sort". Or is it an issue of efficiency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can sort the list by the first 6 characters and then use `Collectors.joining` to separate each string with a `"\n"` delimiter.

```
String result = myList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.substring(0,6)))
                               .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Comment: I accepted this answer, but wanted to ask what "e" is here.

Comment: `e` is an identifier representing the current string object. see https://www.callicoder.com/java-lambda-expression-tutorial/ for an intro to lambdas.

Comment: my bad, I thought it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement a comparator just to compare the first 6 characters:

```
class FirstSixCharComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return a.substring(0,6)compareTo(b.substring(0,6));
    }
}
```

Then use the comparator to perform a sort:

```
Collections.sort(list, new FirstSixCharComparator<String>());   //for collections    
Arrays.sort(array, new FirstSixCharComparator<String>());       //for arrays
```

Answer (score -1):

this piece of code should solve your problem , if its not then we can write comparator kind of stuff to satisfy whatever requirement you have of it.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add("AOPSIKDDD23495");
        words.add("BWLMBEPMI00001");
        Collections.sort(words);
        System.out.println(words);      
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is what you suggest wouldn't solve the main issue I'm having : Sorting only by the first 6 characters. If the first 6 characters are equal and the following three aren't, the two of them shouldn't be particularly sorted since the first 6 are the same.

Comment: okay take this sample set as an example, [AOPSIKDDD23495, AOPSIKMMM23495, AOPSIKZZZ23495]
and tell me what do you expect as an output